# Get nunit (2.5.10) TestCases with parameters from dll

Tags: c#, testing, reflection, nunit, testcase

I got a compiled dll and I need to run every TestCase from this dll seperately with the nunit console tool, one test after the other. To run a TestCase I need to read the name and the parameters of the TestCase from the dll.

I tried reflection, but so far I ran into several problems. Is there a simple way  to get the whole TestCase to run it with the nunit console? I heard of the --explore option of nunit3 to get all information of a dll, but unfortunately I have to use the version 2.5.10.

First of all I do not get the amount of methods defined when I try this:

```
List<MethodInfo> testMethods = new List<MethodInfo>(from type in 
    assembly.GetTypes()
    from method in type.GetMethods()                                                                       
    where method.IsDefined(typeof(TestAttribute)) || 
          method.IsDefined(typeof(TestCaseAttribute))
    select method);
```

Afterwards I iterate over the items of the list and try to get the corresponding parameters with "CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(method)". But every TestCase has a different signature, so its difficult building the form nunit-console wants, like so: methodname(param1,...,paramN)

```
foreach (CustomAttributeData cad in attributes)
            {
                String test = method.Name + "(";
                String attr = String.Empty;

                foreach (CustomAttributeTypedArgument cata in cad.ConstructorArguments)
                {
                    if (cata.Value.GetType() == typeof(ReadOnlyCollection<CustomAttributeTypedArgument>))
                    {
                        foreach (CustomAttributeTypedArgument cataElement in
                        (ReadOnlyCollection<CustomAttributeTypedArgument>)cata.Value)
                        {
                            if (cataElement.ArgumentType.Name == "String")
                            {
                                String elem = String.Empty;
                                if (cataElement.Value == null)
                                {
                                    attr += "null" + ",";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    elem = cataElement.Value.ToString().Replace(@"\", @"\\");
//escape quotation marks
                                    attr += @"\" + "\"" + elem + @"\" + "\"" + ",";
                                }
                            }

                            else if (cataElement.ArgumentType.IsEnum)
                            {
                                var enumName = cataElement.ArgumentType.Name;
                                foreach (var fieldInfo in cataElement.ArgumentType.GetFields())
                                {
                                    if (fieldInfo.FieldType.IsEnum)
                                    {
                                        var fName = fieldInfo.Name;
                                        var fValue = fieldInfo.GetRawConstantValue();

                                        if (cataElement.Value.ToString().Equals(fValue.ToString()))
                                        {
                                            attr += fName + ",";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                attr += cataElement.Value + ",";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    else if (cata.ArgumentType.IsEnum)
                    {
                        var enumName = cata.ArgumentType.Name;
                        foreach (var fieldInfo in cata.ArgumentType.GetFields())
                        {
                            if (fieldInfo.FieldType.IsEnum)
                            {
                                var fName = fieldInfo.Name;
                                var fValue = fieldInfo.GetRawConstantValue();

                                if (cata.Value.ToString().Equals(fValue.ToString()))
                                {
                                    attr = fName;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    else if (cata.Value.GetType() == typeof(String))
                    {
                        String elem = String.Empty;
                        if (cata.Value == null)
                        {
                            attr = "null";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            elem = cata.Value.ToString().Replace(@"\", @"\\");
                            attr = @"\" + "\"" + elem + @"\" + "\"";
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        attr = cata.ToString();
                    }
    //do stuff to get form of TestCase
```

Indeed it needs to be refactored, but I wonder if there is an easier way to get all TestCases and its Parameters.

Comment: "ran into several problems" - what does that mean?

Comment: Please [edit] you question to include additional information -- you can't put large code samples in comments

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do or why. Running each test in an assembly is what nunit-console already does. Running a single test by name is also possible, in which case you don't have to supply the data since each test has it's own data specified by an attribute. Note also that you **can** use the nunit3 explore option to list tests from an nunit 2.5.10 compiled assembly.

Comment: I know that it maybe is not clear why I have to do it in this way. But unfortunately I have to. There are thousands of TestCases which I cant edit. My goal is a database of all TestCases with their Arguments which are stored in a dll.Also I have to use the NUnit 2.5.10 in this special environment and I cant change this version of nunit.